# Resolve generics by type

Tags: c#, generics, types, autofac, quartz.net

I need to resolve some Quartz jobs from Autofac's LifeTimeScope. Currently I have implemented factory  class:

```
public class JobWrapper<T> : IJob where T : IJob
```

In another class I have method that returns resolved job:

```
public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        Type type = bundle.JobDetail.JobType;
        return _lifetimeScope.Resolve<JobWrapper<type>>(); // does not work
    }
```

I need to pass generic to JobWrapper class and currently I don't know how to do that.

Comment: [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class that implements IJob interface

Comment: Where is it defined?

Comment: How did you register the `JobWrapper` class?

Comment: updater.RegisterGeneric(typeof(JobWrapper<>));

Answer (score 3):

You can describe the type yourself

```
// The type will be the Type for JobWrapper<CleanJob>
var type = typeof(JobWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(CleanJob));
return (IJob)container.Resolve(type);

// CleanJob decleration
public class CleanJob : IJob
```

There are some good examples for MakeGenericType [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://omegacoder.com/?p=38).

Comment: Certainly `string` does not implement `IJob`... otherwise good answer.

Comment: @galenus I never said it does. The type is `JobWrapper<string>`.

Comment: There is a generic constraint on `T` in `JobWrapper` declaration. It's not only an `IJob` itself, but also wraps an `IJob`.

Comment: Tried it before and it could not resolve symbol 'bundle'. var type = typeof(JobWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(bundle.JobDetail.JobType));

Comment: @Daemon025 `bundle` is a member and not a type. What is `JobType`? If it's on of the type `Type` then there is no reason for that to work.

Comment: @Daemon025 For what you want it would be without the typoeof `MakeGenericType(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);`

Comment: JobType is a System.Type and since it is a Type already, there is no point of using 'typeof'. Your sample works if the 'typeof' keyword is removed.

Comment: @Daemon025 In my code `CleanJob` is a class I invented and it works great with my sample. I will edit my code to make it more clear.

Comment: @mot don't forget that Quartz has it's own built-in jobs and they should be resolved, too.

Comment: @Daemon025 Never tried to imply you can't just `MakeGenericType(myTypeParameter);` it's just less readable inline, typeof is more clear for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out:

```
public class InjectorJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public InjectorJobFactory(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var type = typeof(JobWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
        return (IJob)_lifetimeScope.Resolve(type);
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {

    }
}
```

I just created another method and then just used MakeGenericMethod

Comment: Your code is not better than mot's. In addition, you are using too much reflection and unnecessary methods. Working directly on methods of `ILifetimeScope` is shorter and clearer.

Comment: It's the same principle as in my solution but with more classes and code, are you sure this suits you better?

Comment: @galenus, I agree that mot's code is better. The solution is updated.